# Is it bad to use Reflection in production code?

Tags: php, reflection

I've got a `Validator` class which creates an instance of a `Validations` class, which contains all the validation methods. When a validation is performed, `__call` in `Validator` is used to dispatch a call `Validator->validate_method` to `Validations->method`.

So for instance, there is a method in `Validations` called `length_of`. When the following code is run:

```
$v = new Validator();
$v->validate_length_of(...);
```

the `length_of` validation in the `Validations` class is executed.

In order to ensure that `__call` doesn't try to dispatch to an invalid or non-public `Validation` method, I use `ReflectionMethod` to check the specified method:

```
$method = new ReflectionMethod($this->validations, $validation_method);
if (!$method->isPublic())
{
  // error
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is the only way to determine whether or not a method is public, but I'm not sure if Reflection is appropriate to have in production code. Is this a code smell?

Comment: Visibility modifiers is what smells here. Simply remove "private" and use "method_exists".

Comment: @stereofrog I'm not trying to access a private method. I'm trying to *not* allow private methods to be accessed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really shouldn't use Reflection in production code. Why don't you use [`is_callable`](http://php.net/is_callable) here?

```
if (!is_callable(array('Validations', $validation_method)) {
    throw new LogicException('method does not exist');
}
```

This checks that the `Validations` class has a static method `$validation_method` and ensures that you may call it from current context. Actually this gives you even more flexibility then reflection, because this takes `__call` methods and similar stuff into account that Reflection doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear in my question, the methods in `Validations` aren't static methods.

Comment: In that case instead of `'Validations'` use `new Validations` (or an existing instance of `Validations`) as first element in the array ;)

Comment: You forgot the array ;) You must pass an array to `is_callable` (if you use it this way.)

Comment: Ah crap, I did indeed. That was a brainfart, especially since I use callbacks all over the place in my class. :)

Comment: Why shouldn't one use Reflection in production code? I don't see any reason for that beyond "know what you do and keep it simple".

Answer (score 1):

If you need the power of the Reflection API in your code, then use it. But Reflection can be slow and a benchmark can never hurt when you use it. In the end only you can decide whether it has too much of an impact on your application. It's still microseconds we are talking about only.

However, for your specific usecase, I dont see why you would use Reflection at all. Just use an interface and make validations into separate classes implmenting that interface. See my [example Validation class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253067/php-classes-validation/3253781#3253781).

If you want to use `__call` with that (magic methods are slow too btw), you can use [`class_implements`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php) to check if the validator implements the interface and then you are sure the validate method exists, e.g. in the main Validator class add

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    if ( class_exists( $method )) {
        $validator = new $method;
        if($validator instanceof IValidate) {
            return call_user_func(array($validator, 'validate'), $args);
        }
        throw new BadMethodCallException('Class exists but is not a Validator');
    }
    throw new RuntimeException('Method does not exist');
}
```

On a sidenote: [the Zend Framework already has an extensive number of Validators you can build on](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html). Since ZF is a component library, you can use them without having to migrate your entire application to ZF. PEAR also has a [Validation package.](http://pear.php.net/package/Validate/docs/0.8.4/Validate/Validate.html)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I would stray away from using reflection in production code.  Instead of trying to call validate_*something* I would create an interface that has the validate method required.  Then for each valiadtor class, you just call $valid->validate().  It would be easier for the interpretor to cache that code.